# using the google maps API - marker cluster

Tags: php, javascript, api

I really am a JS noob - I have never really used itbefore and am struggling using the marker clusterer google provide. I have rad the documentation

here is the code

```
<script src="http://localhost/wheredidmytweetgo/js/markercluster.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
function load() {
  if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
    var map = new GMap2(
    document.getElementById("map"));
    map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
    map.setCenter(
    new GLatLng( 56.65622649350222, -19.86328125), 2);
    var mc = new MarkerClusterer(map);
    function createMarker(point, text, title) {
      var marker =
      new GMarker(point,{title:title});
      GEvent.addListener(
      marker, "click", function() {
        marker.openInfoWindowHtml(text);
      });
      return marker;
    }
    <?php

    foreach ($cluster_location as $location) {
    ?>
    var marker = createMarker(
    new GLatLng(<?php echo $location ?>),
    'Marker text <?php echo $location ?>',
    'Example Title text <?php echo $location ?>');
    map.addMarker(marker);
    <?php }
  ?>
  }
}
```

cluster location is just an array of lat and longs - My code is working fine when just using the add.overlay however there are too many to make the map readable hence the need for clustering. I do load the clustering JS which I have I have included.
I create the clusterer object and pass in map as defined.

```
var markers = [];
//create array
```

I know I can create a JS array and pass this in to

```
var mc = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
```

But I simply dont have the JS knowledge to create an array at this time (I intend to learn) and the Google documentation advises you can iterate and add one at a time using `addMarker`

Hi Tom - Thanksfor the info - I have tried doing what you advised and have came up with the below:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/wheredidmytweetgo/js/markercluster.js">

    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        var center = new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419);

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          'zoom': 13,
          'center': center,
          'mapTypeId': google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        var markers = [];
       <?php foreach ($cluster_location as $location) { ?>{
         var marker = new google.maps.Marker({'position': <?php echo $location;?>});
  markers.push(marker);
}
        <?
       }
       ?>
        var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>A simple example of MarkerClusterer (100 markers)</h3>
    <p>
      <a href="?compiled">Compiled</a> |
      <a href="?">Standard</a> version of the script.
    </p>
    <div id="map-container"><div id="map"></div></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

But my map still loads empty. I'm using literally the most basic google provided code now and just loading my own markers in. I know my markers positioning should be okay because when I go to view my page source I can see

```
{

          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({'position': 40.0994425,-74.9325683});

         markers.push(marker);

          });
```

for each marker. any more help would really be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the examples on google maps utilities library page ([link](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/docs/examples.html)).

But basically to add instance of an object (a marker) to an array you have to define the array first so you need to do the `var markers = [];` above the loop where you create the markers. And then as you create the markers you have to add them to the markers array by calling the `push` method of an array (while you are at it go to MDN and read about arrays! if you want to learn it's good time to start there - there is a tutorial about JS there as well ([link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)).

So inside of the `foreach` loop afer you've defined a marker just add it to the array `markers.push(marker);` This will make the markers available for the `MarkerCluster` initialization.

In a longer term when you figure out javascript a bit better you'll probably want to replace this part with either passing data as JSON object to the DOM so methods can handle it or even better - have the data for markers be retrieved with ajax query. But one step at a time I guess :)

Maybe try the fun interactive tutorials at the [www.codecademy.com](http://www.codecademy.com/)? They are quite basic but seems like that's exactly what you need

EDIT:

```
var marker,
    markers = [];

<?php foreach ($cluster_location as $location) { ?>
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({'position': <?php echo $location;?>});
    markers.push(marker);
<? } ?>
```

Comment: hi tom I have added some more information above . sorry to trouble!

Comment: check the edit in my reply - you've outputted curly bracers to HTML and it produces invalid JS code. Try if it works and let me know :) I've also moved the declaration of marker variable out of the loop so it gets declared only once.